# What would happen to the electric field if the charge it produced suddenly disappeared?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, charge

Suppose we have a charge $q$, which produces an electric field $E$. As the title says, I want to know what will happen to the electric field (E) if the charge q disappears suddenly? Does the electric field (E) disappear instantaneously (after q disappears) or does it persist and propagate through space for a while before disappearing?

I know charge can't just disappear suddenly (because it would violate the law of conservation of charge and a bunch of other things), but since this is a thought experiment I think we can just ignore the above.

Comment: Asking what can happen after something that cannot happen happens is mostly nonsense.

Comment: The charge can't disappear as was elaborated, but it can be screened. Imagine a charge in a metal box with a movable lid. When the lid is closed, the external field will disappear (but there will be a field inside the box). In practice this is how a dipole antenna above a grounded plane works,, except that we aren't using a mechanical "shutter" but are screening the electrons in the antenna with the positively charged nuclei. Take one more step and forget about the ground plane. Now you have a full dipole radiator in free space. That's the physics of "disappearing charges": dipole radiation.

Comment: @Flatterman It takes a finite amount of time to close the lid.

Comment: @Farcher I was giving a realistic comment that will help the OP to establish a working physical intuition.

Comment: @FlatterMann a metal shell doesn't screen away the field of an internal charge. You still see that same field outside the box unless you add extra stuff to your setup.

Comment: @Triatticus Dang. I was trying to be too smart for my own good. You are, of course, correct. The total charge can't be screened. The scenario I was thinking about was still just charge separation inside a Faraday cage, but it is not what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @FlatterMann you can achieve it through a grounded box though so that "magic" box I believe is still feasible :)

Comment: @Triatticus Yes, that's why I was getting back to the grounded dipole and then to the free dipole. But the first step in my comment was absolutely wrong. A free unbalanced charge can't be screened by a collection of balanced charges. A charged plasma stays a charged plasma, no matter whether the extra charge is near the surface or deep inside. Even the grounded dipole (argument from mirror charge) is a bit vacuous because it introduces an impossible system (there is no infinite ground plane).

Answer (score 3):

Curious what other people have to say - this might not be the only/a complete answer.

I'd say the answer is undefined (or perhaps it doesn't matter). Charge conservation is baked into the Maxwell equations. If you wanted to allow charge to disappear, it's actually up to you to make up a new set of equations that's consistent with the Maxwell equations while charge is conserved but does something else sensible when charge isn't conserved. Watch this:

$$
\nabla\cdot \mathbf{E}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}
$$
$$
\nabla\cdot \partial_t\mathbf{E}=\frac{\partial_t\rho}{\epsilon_0}
$$
$$
c^2\nabla\cdot \left(\nabla\times \mathbf{B}-\mu_0\mathbf{j}\right)=\frac{\partial_t\rho}{\epsilon_0}
$$
$$
0=\partial_t\rho+\nabla\cdot\mathbf{j}
$$
This is the charge conservation equation, derived from only the Maxwell equations. It can be phrased as "the change in charge density in a particular place is how much net charge is flowing into or out of that place."

So when you ask "what do the Maxwell equations say happens when charge disappears without going anywhere" the Maxwell equations just say "no."

Put another way, you might wonder what happens over time if you had an electric field that looked like it was produced by a point charge, but the point charge wasn't there. You might think that there's some kind of propagation outward of spherically symmetric waves. Instead, the Maxwell equations just say "this isn't an electric field, it doesn't follow the Poisson equation."

Comment: My only question to a theorist would be about the generalization. Scalar wave theory (longitudinal "compression" waves) allows for oscillating point sources. Maxwell only allows for dipoles and GR, if I remember correctly, only allows for quadrupole emissions because of the rank-2 tensor nature of the theory. I was always assuming that this is a general geometric property of these fields, but I might be wrong. Is this really the case?